# Invalid Sample Rate

Tags: python

I am running a Speech Recognition/PyAudio module on Raspberry PI.
Every time I try to run my program, i end up with this message...

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/Projects/EDWIN $ python edwin.py
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Expression 'SetApproximateSampleRate( pcm, hwParams, sr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1968
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2643
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2767
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "edwin.py", line 6, in <module>
with sr.Microphone() as source:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 76, in __enter__
input = True, # stream is an input stream
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Projects/EDWIN/pyaudio.py", line 714, in open
stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Projects/EDWIN/pyaudio.py", line 396, in __init__
self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997
```

Please help me. I don't know where to edit the sample rate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the command `arecord` to record audio. I had this same problem a while back.

Simply add `--rate 48000` to your `arecord` command.

**If you are using pocketsphinx for your speech recognition:**

Then you also need to add `-samprate 48000` to your pocketsphinx command.

Comment: Update: I figured out the problem. Now I have a different error...
It now says input overflowed. I'm guessing it has something to do with the number of chunks?